# Surveyjs pegar a tag title ao inves da name no resultado

Tags: jquery

Estou usando a biblioteca do `Surveyjs` editor, porém no editor o resultado esta sendo salvo utilizando o `name` como referência para colocar no resultado.

Exemplo : `Survey Result: {"question1":"item1","question2":"item2"}.`

Exemplo do `Json` que cria o questionário no editor :

```
{
 pages: [
  {
   name: "page1",
   elements: [
    {
     type: "radiogroup",
     name: "question1",
     title: "Sobre sua vida",
     choices: [
      "item1",
      "item2",
      "item3"
     ]
    },
    {
     type: "radiogroup",
     name: "question2",
     title: "Sobre seus carros",
     choices: [
      "item1",
      "item2",
      "item3"
     ]
    }
   ]
  }
 ]
}
```

Resultado que estou tentando obter :

```
Survey Result: {"Sobre sua vida":"item1","Sobre seus carros":"item2"}.
```

Este é o link do componente : [Editor surveyjs](https://surveyjs.io/Survey/Builder/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você precisa alterar o JSON padrão gerado pelo componente. Para isso basta fazer um `for in` no objeto alterando a chave *name* por *title*:

```js
Survey.Survey.cssType = "bootstrap";

var surveyJSON = {"pages":[{"name":"page1","elements":[{"type":"radiogroup","name":"question2","title":"pergunta 1","choices":["item1","item2","item3"]},{"type":"radiogroup","name":"question1","title":"pergunta 2","choices":["item1","item2","item3"]}]}]}

// aqui eu altero o JSON
var objJson = surveyJSON.pages[0].elements;
for(var item in objJson){
   objJson[item].name = objJson[item].title;
}

function sendDataToServer(survey) {
    //send Ajax request to your web server.
    alert("The results are:" + JSON.stringify(survey.data));
}

var survey = new Survey.Model(surveyJSON);
$("#surveyContainer").Survey({
    model: survey,
    onComplete: sendDataToServer
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://surveyjs.azureedge.net/1.0.18/survey.jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="surveyContainer"></div>
```

Comment: dvd, obrigado pelo retorno, realizei alguns teste e esta funcionando, porem estou tentando realizar isso quando chamo a função "survey.onComplete.add" , pois existe uma opção de visibleif do componente que utiliza a tag name , e se eu alterar essa tag name antes o visibleif não ira funcionar. Se tiver alguma outra sugestão , Agradeço.

Comment: Ok... vou analisar e já te dou uma resposta

Comment: Será que clonando o JSON e deixando o original intacto. Como seria essa função "survey.onComplete.add"?

Comment: survey.onComplete.add(function (result) { }); ela é disparada após confirmar que o questionário está completo entao pelo result.data, coleto o resultado porem ele não vem como o formato que preciso,acho que clonando não ira funcionar... estou perdendo os cabelos já de tanto pensar nisso.

Comment: Então, o result.data é o retorno da pesquisa. Se vc criar uma variavel que armazene o result.data, tipo `resultado = result.data;` vc pode fazer as alterações que propus e usar as duas coisas de forma diferente.

Comment: Entendi dvd, muito obrigado pela ajuda!!! Com isso em mente vou conseguir finalizar este codigo , Vlww!!

Comment: Legal... espero que dê certo. Não deixe de marcar o famoso ✓ para encerrar a questão. Se precisa basta chamar.